# Foreach dentro de While

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, while

Captura em um array os valores recebidos via post de checkbox marcados, esses checkbox tem os valores iguais aos nomes dos campos da tabela, preciso fazer uma consulta com while e imprimir os campos referentes a array:

```
<?php
    $campos = '`'.implode('`, `', $_POST['check']).'`';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,$campos FROM chamado where status = 1");
    while($busca=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td width="2%"><?php echo $busca['id'];?></td>
        <?php
            foreach ($quantidade_item as $tags) {
                echo '<td width="2%">'.$busca[$tags].'</td>';
            }
        ?>
    </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

O que acontece é que ao executar o código, se for verificado que apenas um checkbox foi marcado, a listagem aparece normalmente, mas, caso marque mais de um checkbox, a listagem exibe apenas os dados da primeira coluna, as outras colunas me retornam undefined index –

Comment: Não percebí bem o problema. Podes explicar melhor/por outras palavras?

Comment: SIm, faltou informar o problema. O que acontece é que ao executar o código, se for verificado que apenas um checkbox foi marcado, a listagem aparece normalmente, mas, caso marque mais de um checkbox, a listagem exibe apenas os dados da primeira coluna, as outras colunas me retornam undefined index

Comment: Ok, e o que dá `var_dump($_POST['check']);` se colocares na primeira linha desse código que mostras`

Comment: Desculpa a demora, tive problemas com minha hospedagem, bom, ao executar o codigo e informar a linha que disse me retorna: `array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "cpf_cnpj" [1]=> string(13) "data_cadastro" [2]=> string(10) "id_cliente" }` , sendo que no exemplo marquei 3 check

Comment: e se marcares só um checkbox como vem o `var_dump`? coloca o teu HTML também para perceber melhor. Não precisas de `\`` no $campos.

Comment: Apenas um check `array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "cpf_cnpj" }`, ao marcar um check a consulta funciona normalmente, ao passar mais checks da variaveis indefinidas e retorna na table apenas os valorse de uma coluna

Comment: não entendi muito bem o seu problema mas tenho uma dica para você, não utilize mysql_query pois o mesmo está obsoleto, aconselho você utilizar PDO ou MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu percebo bem o que queres precisas mudar esta linha:

```
foreach ($quantidade_item as $tags) {
```

Não vejo no teu código de onde vêm essa variável `$quantidade_item` e semanticamente não me faz muito sentido pois penso que o que queres é iterar os campos que vêm do `$_POST` com os dados que foste buscar à BD, certo?

Nesse caso sugiro mudares o código para:

```
foreach ($_POST as $tags) {
```

mas colocar o `$_POST` assim não é boa prática (coloquei só para clarificar o exemplo). Outra coisa que podes mudar é tirar ``` nos campos da query pois não precisa.

Código final:

```
<?php
    $_campos = $_POST['check'];
    $campos = implode(', ', $_campos);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,$campos FROM chamado where status = 1");
    while($busca=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td width="2%"><?php echo $busca['id'];?></td>
        <?php
            foreach ($_campos as $tags) {
                echo '<td width="2%">'.$busca[$tags].'</td>';
            }
        ?>
    </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muito bom ségio, conseguimos solucionar o problema, muito obrigado